# if i have proper credentials, how do i delete LUKS credentials from a different slot?

Tags: luks

i have a LUKS encrypted device, and the key slots are as follows:

0 - former colleague's passphrase
1 - former colleague's keyfile
4 - my new passphrase
5 - my new keyfile

i know that i can delete my OWN credentials:

```
cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sdX
```

and:

```
cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sdX --key-file=/my/key/file
```

respectively - but i would like to disable the key slots 0 and 1. i tried

```
cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sdX --key-file=/my/key/file --key-slot=0
```

but it removed slot 5, not slot 0. fortunately, i still had slot 4 ...

thanks

.rm

Answer (score 0):

it seems as per the manual, luksKillSlot is the way to go. somehow i missed it in the docu.

```
do cryptsetup luksKillSlot /dev/sdX 0 --key-file=/my/key/file
```